# In Aster, how do I use CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS and what version of postgres am I using?

Tags: teradata, teradata-aster

We're using Aster for some of our web session logs. I've been told internally that Aster uses `PostgreSQL`, and in fact for a lot of my queries, I look on this site and follow the guidelines for `PostgreSQL` code, which always work.

Now, I'm trying to use a simple query that keeps failing (Syntax error at or near "NOT"):

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS scratchdb.test_table
(partition key(uvn)) as
select distinct date(created_dt) as full_date,uvn,user_id from db.db_table
```

I keep getting errors on `IF NOT EXISTS`. So I found another article that says I need at least `PostgreSQL-9.1` for `IF NOT EXISTS` to work. In order to find out what version I'm on, that article recommends:

```
select version();
```

But that returns an error :

```
function version is not supported
```

So, Aster must not be 100% `PostgreSQL`. My two questions are, how do I use `IF EXISTS` when creating a table in Aster, and how do I tell what version of `PostgreSQL` I am using?

Comment: @CraigRinger http://www.asterdata.com/

Comment: Thanks @PeterEisentraut - yes, "Aster" is indeed Terradata Aster, which is (theoretically) just an implementation of PostgreSQL. When looking for help for Aster, you can't google "aster question I have" as there are very few results; you need to google "postgres question I have".

Comment: Ah, familiar to me as Terradata. Sorry.

Comment: Have a look in the data directory on the file system. (If you don't know where it is, it's possible that `SHOW data_directory` will tell you, but again it depends on how customised this PostgreSQL flavour is). In the datadir there might be a file named `PG_VERSION` ... again, unless they've removed that as part of their changes to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two SQL statements when dropping / creating table in Aster:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS scratchdb.test_table;
CREATE TABLE scratchdb.test_table ...
```

Also, I don't recommend consulting Postgres documentation newer than version 8.3 and even then it's no guarantee that Aster supports function or feature found there. Aster does indeed have a lot of similarities with Postgres but it is not the same.

So, there is no version of PosgreSQL - it's only version of Aster that matters. One way to check it is via admin console (AMC): point your browser to `https://server_name_or_ip_address`

After logging in click ***Admin: Cluster Management: Nodes*** tab. It displays all the nodes present in the cluster, along with software version information.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the great answer (I can't upvote it yet, no reputation).